# Blackberry jre configuration

Tags: blackberry

I am new to that Blackberry development platform.

I installed eclipse plugin for blackberry successfully.

Now when creating the project its showing no jre click configure jre when clicked and configure and select whenever option its shows the same error then I go to that update site and install the sdk but after downloading its shows error like

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=SDKProfile..

Please help me create my first BB app here.

<sub>Can't send more logs because I have 9 reputation and require 10 reputation for adding hyperlinks</sub>

Comment: the second para isn't very clear. `now when creating...`

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this out

- Remove BlackBerry plugin from Eclipse, shut eclipse down.
- Next go to BlackBerry developer website (register, its free I think), get the correct SDK your handset has, install it.
- Add the home directory of this SDK to your path.
- Now launch Eclipse, go get the BlackBerry plugin and install it. Now try creating a BlackBerry project, it should work.

If it doesnt, try running one of the sample apps that get shipped with the SDK in Eclipse, say the "Hello World" app. If it works, modify it for your project.